# Groupby code with min_max year calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Dataframe:

```
Date               Code          
2019               ab            
2019               cd
2019               ab
2017               ab
2018               ab
2018               cd
2016               cd
2016               cd
```

Output:

```
Date               Code            Max_year_count-Min_year_count          
2019               ab              1        
2019               cd             -1
2019               ab              1
2017               ab              1
2018               ab              1
2018               cd             -1
2016               cd             -1
2016               cd             -1
```

The aim is to create `Max_year_count-Min_year_count` column.
For example, calculation for `Code column ab` (row 1):
 `(count of occurrence of code ab in max_year i.e 2019)-(count of occurrence of code ab in min_year i.e 2017)` = 2-1 = 1

Thanks !!

Comment: dont think there is any ab in 2016

Comment: Not mandatory for `ab` to be in 2016. Min and Max year might vary for different Code, thanks @sammywemmy, also edited my question

Comment: Your `DataFrame` has only one `2016` entry but the output 2 `2016`'s. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes typo, fixed it, and sorry about that @Ch3steR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. Not pandas expert there may exist better answer. This should get you started at least.

Using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pd.Index.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.max.html) and [`pd.Index.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.min.html)

```
df
   Date Code
0  2019   ab
1  2019   cd
2  2019   ab
3  2017   ab
4  2018   ab
5  2018   cd
6  2016   cd
7  2016   cd

temp = df.groupby(['Code','Date']).size()
df['Max-Min']=df.Code.apply(lambda x:temp[x][temp[x].index.max()]-temp[x][temp[x].index.min()])

df
   Date Code  Max-Min
0  2019   ab        1
1  2019   cd       -1
2  2019   ab        1
3  2017   ab        1
4  2018   ab        1
5  2018   cd       -1
6  2016   cd       -1
7  2016   cd       -1
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) with the [nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#taking-the-nth-row-of-each-group) function can help here  :

#get a frequency count of Code per year

```
res = (pd.crosstab(df.Code,df.Date)
       .stack()
        #this gets rid of entries for empty years
       .loc[lambda x: x.ne(0)]
      )

#subtract first from last ... years are already sorted from min to max
mapping = res.groupby('Code').nth(-1) - res.groupby('Code').nth(0)

print(mapping)

Code
ab    1
cd   -1
dtype: int64

df['Max_Min'] = df.Code.map(mapping)

print(df)

    Date    Code    Max_Min
0   2019    ab       1
1   2019    cd      -1
2   2019    ab       1
3   2017    ab       1
4   2018    ab       1 
5   2018    cd      -1
6   2016    cd      -1
7   2016    cd      -1
​
```